# Event Complete Callbacks with Opal-jQuery

Tags: opalrb, opal

I am working on a project that handles multiple jQuery events in succession using the opal-jquery wrapper. jQuery has very effective callback functionality and I am wondering if it is possible to do this in pure ruby with Opal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [Promise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) which is a technique to manage long-term asynchronous events and avoid callback-hell. In regular Opal you would do for example:

```
HTTP.get("url") do |response|
  puts "got response"
end
```

With promises, this becomes:

```
HTTP.get("url").then do |response|
  puts "got response"
end
```

The difference lies in the `then` which returns the Promise (see http://opalrb.org/docs/promises/). The code block will be executed when the HTTP get returns with content (or an error).

Also check up this article on how to use promises with opal-jquery

http://opalrb.org/blog/2014/05/07/promises-in-opal/

Comment: That is really helpful! I see that the HTTP method get responds with a promise that is fulfilled. How would I modify a custom method of my own to return a promise and fix the "callback hell"

Comment: [Answers should not entirely depend on external links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259). Stack Overflow trying to build a stable long-term resource. Answers need to directly contain enough information to be useful even if the links are broken. Please edit your answer to include at least the essential information, or else it may be deleted or converted to a comment. (Don't just copy and paste. Plagiarized content would also be deleted.) Thanks!